# (discord.py) How do I make it so that the bot automatically changes a specific user's nickname at a fixed time everyday?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The nickname has a number that increases by 1 everyday. I'm familiar with creating a command to change a user's nickname that I have to type out to work, but I have no idea how to make the bot automatically do it everyday without me having to type out the command. I experimented with making the bot type out the command but I'm having trouble figuring out the increasing number.

Comment: Just use `@tasks.loop` it will do your work for every time given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command at the time you want and it will repeat it every 12 hours.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@tasks.loop(hours=12)
async def chnick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await member.edit(nick=nick)
    
@client.command
async def start_nick_change(ctx,member:discord.Member,nick):
  chnick.start(ctx,member,nick)

client.run(your_token)
```